# Grails - computer/browser locale doesn't affects i18n mechanism

Tags: grails, browser, internationalization, operating-system, locale

I'm having a weird problem or maybe i failed to understand how Grails i18n mechanism works.

I inserted the following to my index.gsp file:

```
LocaleContextHolder.locale:              '${org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder.locale}'
java.util.Locale.getDefault():           '${java.util.Locale.getDefault()}'
RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request):  '${org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)}'
session['SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE']: '${session['org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE']}'
```

This code snippet should print the Locale, and it does like so:

> LocaleContextHolder.locale:              'iw'
>
> java.util.Locale.getDefault():           'en_US'
>
> RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request):  'iw'
>
> session['SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE']: ''

The above is my default output when i run the given code snippet.

I tried to understand what exactly affects this variables so i did the next steps:

1. I changed Chrome's Locale

   Settings --> Show advanced settings --> Language and input settings)
2. I changed my operating system's locale (Windows 7)

   Control panel --> Region and language --> Format + Location + System locale

After those changes i rebooted my computer and expected the values of the locale variables to change, but they still remain the same.

I'm aware i can change the Locale with the ?lang parameter & with some code, but i'm interested in letting Grails to decide which Locale to pick.

What exactly affects those variables? how does Grails decide the machine's locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the user Locale is detected from the incoming Accept-Language HTTP header, this header is generated by the browser that is used by the user. 
Each browser determines the system Locale differently:

1. Internet Explorer uses the O/S Locale settings.
2. Firefox / Chrome let the user to decide what Locale to use (In the language settings).

See: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities.en.php

Answer (score 0):

**15.2 Changing Locales**

By default the user locale is detected from the incoming Accept-Language header. However, you can provide users the capability to switch locales by simply passing a parameter called lang to Grails as a request parameter:
/book/list?lang=es
Grails will automatically switch the user's locale and store it in a cookie so subsequent requests will have the new header.

from here :
https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.3/guide/i18n.html

If you are deploying in tomcat you can set the locale in the **catalina.sh** script:

```
if [ -z "$LOGGING_MANAGER" ]; then
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US"
else 
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $LOGGING_MANAGER -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US"
fi
```

Comment: I'm aware i can manipulate the Locale by the lang parameter & by code.
But shouldn't i18n detected the machine's Locale and select the relevant one?

Comment: you can set the locale of the tomcat/jetty server

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA14 & it's running on tomcat. can you explain how to change this setting?

Comment: Oh didn't see it in your answer!

Comment: Where is this file exactly in my project?

Comment: it should be at the bin folder of your tomcat installation

Comment: I'm running on windows, can i add this code to my catalina.bat file?

Comment: yeah. that is the windows version of that file

Answer (score 0):

I think the internationalization works when you pass lang parameter in the URL. It's mentioned in the documentation

```
By default the user locale is detected from the incoming Accept-Language header. 
However, you can provide users the capability to switch locales by simply passing
       a parameter called lang to Grails as a request parameter:
                /book/list?lang=es
```

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/i18n.html